# Can't implement Jquery Ui slider for a DecimalField for a model in Django

Tags: django, jquery-ui, django-models, django-forms, jquery-ui-slider

Just started to fuse JQuery UI with my app. Apparently the slider only works on div elements. I have a form based on a model(ModelForm). One of the fields is a Decimal Field like so:

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
    ...
```

being created like so:

```
class modelCreate(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'form.html'
    model = mymodel
```

form.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
    <!--<script src='http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js'></script>-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Content/css/startTheme/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css' %}" />
    <script src={% static 'Scripts/js/jquery-1.10.2.js' %} ></script>
    <script src={% static 'Scripts/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js' %} ></script>

    <div class="form_container">
        <form action="" id="myform" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <table>
                <tr class="fieldWrapper">
                    <td class="label">
                        <label for="id_rating">Your number:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="field">
                        {{ form.rating }}
                        <div class="error">
                                {{ form.rating.errors }}
                        </div>                            
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">            
                        <div class="btnContainer">
                            <input type="submit" class='btn' value="Create" />    
                        </div>         
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>           
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Using the slider on a normal div that I created works correctly.

But in the form if used on an input element it just changes the color of the border of the input box. It becomes a glorified input box.

Another approach I've thought of is to remove the decimal field on the page, replace with a div, and save that value to the model before commit (throught Form_valid()).

But I'm keeping that solution as a last resort.

A customizable slider is very important for this app. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include your `form.html` as well?

Comment: @Drewness posted the form.html. Removed all the irrelevant stuff as its a big file.

Comment: Fair enough. I assume the field in question is `rating`..?

Comment: @Drewness yes. correct. I fixed the form to reflect the model. So any ideas?

Comment: Yes, but one last question: What precision do you want on the decimal field? Such as `1.10` or `1.09` and so on...

Comment: @Drewness doesn't matter, but 2 decimals places would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to hide the `rating` input field and add a `<div>` for the slider that updates the `rating` value. I've created a simple demo (below) to demonstrate this idea.

**Note:** The demo has a max value of 5. However, declaring your field, `DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)` allows you to store numbers up to 999. This would obviously make it difficult to get the exact number you wanted using a slider.

### DEMO

More specifically for your `form.html`:

```
...
<td class="field">
    {{ form.rating.as_hidden }}
    <div id="rating_slide"></div>
    <div class="error">
        {{ form.rating.errors }}
    </div>                            
</td>
...
```

If you want a more *integrated* method you could create a [mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/mixins/) class for your view or [inclusion-tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) for your template.